# How does folder name translation work in international Windows 7 versions?

Tags: windows, windows-7, internationalization, language-translation

I am running an Italian version of Windows 7.
Some folders, such as `C:\Users`, appear as `C:\Users`
when I run `cmd` and do an `ls` from the `C:` directory.
However, when I use Windows Explorer, this *Users*
folder shows up as *Utenti*. Also, when an
install script installs to C:\Users and I
go to Windows Explorer, I can click on
`C:\Utenti` and still view the stuff.

Can anyone explain where this
translation is configured and how
it works at a deeper level, as this
happens with most folders on the
system which seemingly end up
having two names in the Italian version of Window 7?

Thank you for any pointers or
more in-depth information
concerning the peculiarities
of such mechanism.

Comment: I believe this is accomplished via [LocalizedResourceName entry in desktop.ini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms906608.aspx).  Yes, that is for WinCE but it is the same for real Windows.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but which desktop.ini file are you referring to. When I do a search under Computer I get about 60 or so results for desktop.ini. For instance, the contents of C:\Windows\System32 is [LocalizedFileNames]
migwiz.lnk=@%windir%\system32\migwiz\wet.dll,-588           . Any idas on how to make sense of this. Thanks, John Goche

Comment: Desktop.ini customizes the folder that it is located in.  The value specifies a resource; the path is the DLL in which the resource is located and the number is the resource ID.  This syntax is called an [indirect string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Works also with direct strings, as of: `LocalizedResourceName=New Name`

Comment: Here's a link to a more up to date documentation on Desktop.ini: [How to Customize Folders with Desktop.ini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The localized folders are actually [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to their english counter parts. The original english folders are hidden system files. This way the user only sees the folders in their language but they are still accessible under their english names. This is a big plus of Windows Vista/7 because before if a script accessed `C:\Program Files` it was not usable under non-english versions of Windows.

You can show the hidden original english folders if you go to `tools -> folder options -> show system files` (or something similiar, out of my head).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In my italian version I had to uncheck the following option to do what you suggested: Pannello di controllo -> Aspetto e personalizzazione -> Opzioni cartella -> Nascondi i file protetti di sistema (consigliato). However even with this folder option changed I cannot view Users instead of Utenti in my C:\ folder. Also, how were you able to check that the folder with translated folder name is actually a symbolic link? Thanks. John Goche

Comment: It might be some other option in that menu. Can't tell you the exact one, since I'm running linux at the moment and only remember the german command. I can't tell you for sure they are using symbolic links, but it's a similiar technique and I remember reading an article about it a year ago or so.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot find the option you're mentioning. Could you please tell me the name of the option in German? Could you please let me know next time you boot windows, or, if you find the article, no matter in what language, I would like to be able to read it. Thank you very much. John Goche

Comment: This is definitely not correct for Windows 10. I see all hidden and system folders and `Users` is not among them. On the other hand, the `C:\Benutzer\desktop.ini` does contain a `LocalizedResourceName`. There is other evidence that `Benutzer` is not a symlink, but in fact just the `Users` folder shown with a different name.

Answer (score 3):

As Felix Dombek mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115770/how-does-folder-name-translation-work-in-international-windows-7-versions#comment72956410_11115868), this is due to the [desktop.ini](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-customize-folders-with-desktop-ini), which can be found in your Users folder (and other folders as well).

This file is used by the File Explorer and the Shell to customize the appearance of folders.
The [LocalizedResourceName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms906608(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) entry is responsible for the displayed foldername, which is used to determine the correct DLL and the stringID, the foldername should be loaded from.